# your sd card is full back to vault now

Tags: gallery-vault

By mistake my SD card was formatted. When I copy images out of the app lock vault I'm getting an error message that says my SD card is full.  How can I recover my images?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any Recovery software to recover your SD Card data, you can recover using Android data recovery. Beside this I had seen this thread in Quora you can check out its solution at below link. Here are the steps that he applied:

If you are looking for recovery through App Lock & Gallery Vault App, here are the steps to follow :

- Log in to the App Lock & Gallery Vault using your Master Password.
- Tap on ‘App Lock’ to slide out the menu and access ‘Settings’.
- Simply tap on ‘Data Recovery’, it will recover all your previously lost data from a previous version of App Lock & Gallery Vault.

Original Source:

https://www.quora.com/What-can-I-do-to-recover-photos-from-an-app-lock-vault-showing-files-are-damaged